# How to test my program against an input test case file

Tags: c, windows

I was participating in some coding contests and luckily my code also ran. However my solution was not expected because i was wrong with the pattern of taking input.

---

The question involved taking in an integer as an input and performing some operation and returning a different or same integer. I do not have any problem with the program, I just don't know how to code so as to take inputs like this

---

```
Input

The input will contain several test cases (not more than 10). 
Each test case is a single  line with a number n, 0 <= n <= 1 000 000 000. 
It is the number given as input.

Output

For each test case output a single line, containing the integer returned.
```

---

```
Example

Input:
12
2

Output:
13
2
```

---

My code is

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int functionReturningInteger(int n)
{
// implementation
........ 
return num;
}


int main(void)
{

int number;
//printf("Enter the number: ");
scanf("%d",&number);
printf(functionReturningInteger(number));
return 0;
```

}

---

How am i supposed to know how many inputs they will give ( although they do provide a maximum limit). And if i use an array to store these inputs whose size is equal to the maximum limit, how do i check the size of an integer array in c ?

---

I will appreciate anybody helping out with a small piece of code. Also if am able to test it against an input test file and generate an "output.txt" (output file). I already have the desired output file "des.txt". Then how can i match whether both the files are same or not ?

Comment: you have a bug in your code `printf("%d\n", functionReturningInteger(number));`

Comment: Yeah.. Actually I had to tailor the code to avoid posting unnecessary code. Thanks!

Comment: @gcc The assignment said "no more than 10", so you can safely use a fixed size array in this particular case.

Comment: @MrLister : If i fix the size of an array, say to 10 and then if i get only 5 elements in the array, then how would i count how many elements have been eneterd. I dont know how to find the size of an integer array ?

Comment: If you have ability to see future, you can use static array. But, in most case, if you do not know, use pointer ( allocate heap area ). Or, Initialize static array with a number which will not be in input. Then, take inputs. Afterwards, count until you see the character which will not be in input. ...

Comment: @CSSS You can use a static array of 10 elements and count how many numbers you got in the scanning loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int scanned;
while((scanned = scanf("%d", &number)) != EOF) {
    printf("%d\n", functionReturningInteger(number));
}
```

If `scanf` detects the end of input before a successful conversion, it returns `EOF`.

For the other questions, redirect input and output,

```
$ ./your_prog < input.txt > output.txt
```

and compare

```
$ comp output.txt des.txt
```

Comment: Or, since the OP is running on Windows, just `your_prog` instead of `./yourprog`. And `comp` instead of `diff`.

Comment: What if i want the user to enter say 5 or 6 numbers (not known) and then the output should be generated after that. Will the above work then ?

Comment: @MrLister Aww, dang, missed the tag.

Comment: @CSSS you can test for yourself! Does Ctrl+Z still generate an EOF on Windows?

Comment: @CSSS That prints each result before it scans the next input. But why would you want that? If the input is redirected from a file, you won't see it.

Comment: When i tried doing the same as you mentioned and tried giving inputs from a user, i am able to give as many inputs as i want, however no result gets displayed !!

Comment: With the redirect `> output.txt`, the output goes to the file (I hope I remember that right, that the redirect works too in Windows' command shell, haven't used that for ages). If you omit that and leave only the input redirect, you should see the output in the terminal.

Comment: The above code generates a .depend file. No .exe file is generated and so how can i check it from  the command prompt ?

Comment: Erm, if you compile the code, you surely get an .exe? You can't run it if it isn't an .exe, or can you?

Comment: I am not getting an .exe file ! I am getting a .depend file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14046/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-csss)

Answer (score 0):

You could read line by line until there is nothing to read from file. This way you don't need to know how many inputs is given.

There is no default way to track array size in C.

To match files you can use `diff` on Linux\Unix os.

Comment: I am not supposed to write a file open and read code ! I need to write my program like that and then use command prompmt on windows or terminal commands on linux to do the same.

Comment: stdin, stdout is a file like interface in C. To get data from standard input you read from it like from file ;).